# Red Fish Blue ꟻish

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, optimization

You are presented the following six cards.

[image]

The red cards are rotations of F, and the blue cards are rotations of ꟻ (backwards F). Your goal is to make it so that the red cards are rotations of ꟻ (backwards F) and the blue cards are rotations of F in the minimal number of moves.

**Allowed moves:**

- Rotate a blue card 90 degrees clockwise
- Flip a blue card horizontally (e.g. b becomes d)
- Flip a red card vertically (e.g. P becomes b)

**Restrictions:**

- At no time may any two cards look the same ignoring color.
- At no time may any card look like a normal F. Only a rotation or reflection thereof.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Only because I can't find a Unicode character for an upside-down F. So I'm using P as an example instead. The example would not occur with the actual cards. I'm just using it to accurately demonstrate what "flip vertically" means.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Did I say you can rotate the red cards? :)

Comment: FYI, the reversed-F symbol isn't showing up correctly on my screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z6mI.png

Comment: @Randal'Thor Oh no, I'll fix that.

Comment: @noedne Yes, it looks like "Red Fish Blue *[little box with symbols]* ish".

Comment: @noedne I'd rather leave the title as it is, since it's not important in solving the puzzle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I think I can do it in $10$ moves as follows: rotate b3, rotate b1, flip r3, flip b3, rotate b1, flip r1, flip b2, flip r2, rotate b3, flip b1. I do not have good pictures of this process.

Comment: After you flip r2, I believe r2 and b2 look the same, violating the restriction.

Comment: @Riley Oops, I think I confused r2 and r3.